# Formula result is data type (Text), incompatible with expected data type (Number)

Tags: formula

Trying to create a new summary formula in a report that essentially looks at an op and if it is under 25K it is "under 25K" if it is over 100K then "over 100K" and everything else falls into "25-100"  thoughts

If(Opportunity.ACV_Amount_New__c:SUM < 25000, "Under 25K",
If(Opportunity.ACV_Amount_New__c:SUM > 100000, "Over 100K", "25-100K"))

Comment: try with this formula.. If(TEXT(Opportunity.ACV_Amount_New__c:SUM < 25000), "Under 25K", 
If(TEXT(Opportunity.ACV_Amount_New__c:SUM > 100000), "Over 100K", "25-100K"))

Comment: Incorrect parameter type for function 'Text()'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, Picklist, received Boolean

Comment: Instead of summary formulas, you use bucket field to achieve your requirement. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_bucketing_adding.htm&type=5

Comment: That works a lot better thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of summary formula, you can achieve this requirement by using bucket fields.

Ex: I have taken **Annual Revenue** field for bucket

Edit the respective report, from the left side pane under **bucket field** section, add the bucket field. Refer the below screenshot for your reference.

[image]

Once you click on A**dd bucket field** you get with popup and choose the field you want to bucket. In your case `ACV_Amount_New__c`

Refer the below screenshot for bucket logic.

[image]

Refer the help [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_bucketing_adding.htm&type=5)